# Draw only half of circle

Tags: swift

I want to draw only the left or right half of the circle.

I can draw the circle from 0 to 0.5 (right side) with no problems. But drawing the circle from 0.5 to 1 (left side) doesn't work.

call:

```
 addCircleView(circle, isForeground: false, duration: 0.0, fromValue: 0.5,  toValue: 1.0)
```

This is my code:

```
func addCircleView( myView : UIView, isForeground : Bool, duration : NSTimeInterval, fromValue: CGFloat, toValue : CGFloat ) -> CircleView {
        let circleWidth = CGFloat(280)
        let circleHeight = circleWidth

        // Create a new CircleView
        let circleView = CircleView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, circleWidth, circleHeight))

        //Setting the color.
        if (isForeground == true) {

            circleView.setStrokeColor((UIColor(hexString: "#ffefdb")?.CGColor)!)
        } else {
            // circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
            //Chose to use hexes because it's much easier.
            circleView.setStrokeColor((UIColor(hexString: "#51acbc")?.CGColor)!)
        }

        myView.addSubview(circleView)

        //Rotate the circle so it starts from the top.
        circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.56)

        // Animate the drawing of the circle
        circleView.animateCircleTo(duration, fromValue: fromValue, toValue: toValue)

        return circleView

    }
```

Circle view class

```
import UIKit
extension UIColor {
    /// UIColor(hexString: "#cc0000")
    internal convenience init?(hexString:String) {
        guard hexString.characters[hexString.startIndex] == Character("#") else {
            return nil
        }
        guard hexString.characters.count == "#000000".characters.count else {
            return nil
        }
        let digits = hexString.substringFromIndex(hexString.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
        guard Int(digits,radix:16) != nil else{
            return nil
        }
        let red = digits.substringToIndex(digits.startIndex.advancedBy(2))
        let green = digits.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(digits.startIndex.advancedBy(2)..<digits.startIndex.advancedBy(4)))
        let blue = digits.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(digits.startIndex.advancedBy(4)..<digits.startIndex.advancedBy(6)))
        let redf = CGFloat(Double(Int(red, radix:16)!) / 255.0)
        let greenf = CGFloat(Double(Int(green, radix:16)!) / 255.0)
        let bluef = CGFloat(Double(Int(blue, radix:16)!) / 255.0)
        self.init(red: redf, green: greenf, blue: bluef, alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
    }
}

class CircleView: UIView {

    var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    var from : CGFloat = 0.0;


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        // Use UIBezierPath as an easy way to create the CGPath for the layer.
        // The path should be the entire circle.
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: (frame.size.width - 10)/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)

        // Setup the CAShapeLayer with the path, colors, and line width
        circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        circleLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
        circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

        //I'm going to change this in the ViewController that uses this. Not the best way, I know but alas.
        circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

        //You probably want to change this width
        circleLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;

        // Don't draw the circle initially
        circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0

        // Add the circleLayer to the view's layer's sublayers
        layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)

    }

    func setStrokeColor(color : CGColorRef) {
        circleLayer.strokeColor = color
    }


    // This is what you call if you want to draw a full circle.
    func animateCircle(duration: NSTimeInterval) {
        animateCircleTo(duration, fromValue: 0.0, toValue: 1.0)
    }

    // This is what you call to draw a partial circle.
    func animateCircleTo(duration: NSTimeInterval, fromValue: CGFloat, toValue: CGFloat){
        // We want to animate the strokeEnd property of the circleLayer
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

        // Set the animation duration appropriately
        animation.duration = duration

        // Animate from 0 (no circle) to 1 (full circle)
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = toValue

        // Do an easeout. Don't know how to do a spring instead
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)

        // Set the circleLayer's strokeEnd property to 1.0 now so that it's the
        // right value when the animation ends.
        circleLayer.strokeEnd = toValue

        // Do the actual animation
        circleLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
    }


    // required function
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it fail to animate, or not draw at all?

Comment: It draws only the right part of the circle wich is right. But I want to be able to draw only the left and or right side. The left drawing doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set:

`circleLayer.strokeStart = fromValue`

in the animateCircleTo(duration...) function.

You set the end of the stroke, but not the beginning. Consequently, all circle animations begin from 0.0, even if you intend them to begin at a later part of the stroke.

Like this:

```
// This is what you call to draw a partial circle.
func animateCircleTo(duration: NSTimeInterval, fromValue: CGFloat, toValue: CGFloat){
    // We want to animate the strokeEnd property of the circleLayer
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    // Set the animation duration appropriately
    animation.duration = duration

    // Animate from 0 (no circle) to 1 (full circle)
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = toValue

    // Do an easeout. Don't know how to do a spring instead
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)

    // Set the circleLayer's strokeEnd property to 1.0 now so that it's the
    // right value when the animation ends.
    circleLayer.strokeStart = fromValue
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = toValue

    // Do the actual animation
    circleLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
}
```

Comment: The animation works now from the point. But the full circle is drawn, so it is not possible to draw the half circle on the left side?

Comment: Does your animateCircleTo function like like the one I just pasted in with circleLayer.strokeStart being set?

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Comment: Definitely calling it with from:0.5 and to:1.0, because it works fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to mask or clip out the half of the circle you don't want.

```
class HalfCircleView : UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let p = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 50, height: 100))
        p.addClip()
        let p2 = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 80, height: 80))
        p2.lineWidth = 2
        p2.stroke()
    }
}
```

[image]

Of course, where you put the clipping is where the circle half will appear. And once you have the half-circle view of course you can rotate it etc.

Answer (score 0):

In swift ui. Draws a clock wise arc, with a progress:

[image]

This is the implementation:

```
    struct ArcShape: Shape {
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
    var progress: Double

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        let endAngle = 360.0 * progress - 90.0
        bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: height / 2),
                          radius: width / 3,
                          startAngle: CGFloat(-90 * Double.pi / 180),
                          endAngle:   CGFloat(endAngle * Double.pi / 180),
                          clockwise: true)

        return Path(bezierPath.cgPath)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
            ArcShape(width:  geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, progress: 0.75)
            .stroke(lineWidth: 5)
            .fill(Color(R.color.colorBlue.name))
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width , height: geometry.size.height)
```